# How to dynamically create multiple UL LI from a loop - javascript/jquery/magento

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to read a global variable created by magento-spConfig and create multiple unordered lists based on it. My Javascript code:

```
   if(typeof spConfig !='undefined'){
    if(typeof spConfig[0] == 'undefined' ) {
        spConfig[0] = spConfig;
    }
    var index  = 0 , count = spConfig.length?spConfig.length:1;
    for( var index  = 0 ; index<count;index++) {
        if(typeof spConfig != 'undefined' && typeof spConfig[index].config != 'undefined' && typeof spConfig[index].config.attributes != 'undefined') {
            for(var attributeID in spConfig[index].config.attributes) {

               //alert(attributeID) gives (the number of ul's i want)
                var ul = jQuery('<ul id="clone'+attributeID+'"></ul>');

                for(var optionID in spConfig[index].config.attributes[attributeID].options) {
                    var option = spConfig[index].config.attributes[attributeID].options[optionID];
                    if(typeof option == 'object') {

                       // alert(option.label); gives the number of li's i want

                        var li = $('<li>'+option.label+'</li>');
                        jQuery(".price-info").append(li);
                        jQuery(".price-info").append(ul);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At the end, i am hoping to append the Ul's to some content on my page.
The code above is only creating empty UL's. The LI's are not populated.

Please help.

Comment: You must append the LIs to the UL then append the UL to `.price-info`: `ul.append(li);
                        jQuery(".price-info").append(ul);`  But beware, this could be optimized, concatening a string in loop or using document fragment. Using `append()` in loops like that is really slow

Comment: I tried that, it gives the same result :(

Comment: So are you sure `jQuery(".price-info")` doesn't return a jq empty object? Anyway, you should provide minimalistic sample in question which replicates your issue

Comment: nope the div is not a jq empty obj..i think the appending etc, should not be done in the place it is now..

Comment: `jQuery(".price-info").append(ul);` should be in the outter for loop, after the inner one. BUT the `ul.append(li);` is at the right place

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q7v83ft8/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be appending the `li`s into the `ul` first.

```
ul.append(li);
$('.price-info').append(ul);
```

Comment: It is giving me the same result :(

Comment: i think i am not appending at the right place..could be i should do it in the next loop

Comment: @wasiim_dev It might be beneficial to put your code in a jsfiddle to replicate what you are trying to do

Comment: What is `spConfig` right before you begin checking against it?  Put that in your fiddle instead of using `new Product.Config`

Comment: spConfig contains all the data i need to construct the ul li. I just copied the code i have from my view/source. That is all i have really

Comment: Try putting the `ul.append(li);` in the for-loop where it is created, as A.Wolff suggests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76641/discussion-between-chazsolo-and-wasiim-dev).